# How to dynamically filter JSON data based on category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
 [
    {
        "category": "Beauty",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name": "Baby Care",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "soap",
                        "price": 10.00
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "cream",
                        "price": 20.00
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "dipers",
                         "price": 8.00
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Dress",
                        "price": 13.00
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Drug Store",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bandage",
                         "price": 5.00
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "stringe",
                        "price": 6.50
                    },
                    {
                        "name": " Pain Relief",
                        "price": 8.00
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "First Aid Kit",
                         "price": 14.99
                    },
                   {
                        "name": "Cold Relief",
                        "price": 6.50
                    }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Health and Personal Care",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Household Supplies",
                "items": [{
                        "name": "Air Freshener",
                         "price": 1.25
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "All Purpose Cleaner",
                        "price": 2.99
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Disinfecting Wipes",
                        "price": 8.99
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Pantry Items",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name": "Beverages",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "name": "Apple Juice",
                    "price": 5.99
                  },

                    {
                        "name": "Banana-Orange Juice",
                         "price": 1.99
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "Cranberry Juice",
                         "price": 4.99
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "Strawberry Lemonade",
                        "price": 2.50
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Canned Food",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Pickels",
                        "description": "Assorted pickles",
                        "price": 1.99
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tomatoe Sauce",
                         "price": 1.59
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Perishables",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name": "Bread and Bakery",
                "items": [
                {
                  "name": "Baguette",
                  "price": 3.00
                },
                {
                  "name": "Pie",
                  "price": 5.00
                },
                {
                  "name": "Brownies",
                  "price": 2.50
                }
              ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Cheese",
                "items": [
                {
                  "name": "Feta Cheese",
                   "price": 7.54
                },
                {
                  "name": "Emental Cheese",
                  "price": 8.74
                },
                {
                  "name": "Swiss Cheese",
                  "price": 5.89
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Am working on this project that require fetching items from a JSON file according to categories, when a particular subcategory is clicked, it should display only items from that subcategory but my code is working for only one subcategory but I don't know how to make it dynamic to work for every subcategory

```js
$('#subcategory1').click(function() {
  $.getJSON("list.json",
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      let output = '';
      $.each(data[0].subcategories[0].items, function(index, product) {
        output += `
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="items">
                      <div class='photo'>
                          <img src="${product.imagelink}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="info">
                          <h4>${product.name}</h4>
                          <h5>$${product.price}</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="info">
                          <p>
                              <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           `;
      });

      $('#images').html(output);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="category1">
  <li><a href="#" id="subcategory1">Baby Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="subcategory2">Drug Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="subcategory3">Health and Personal Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="subcategory4">Household Supplies</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How your json looks like?

Comment: When using the Stack Snippet button, please click the Run code snippet before inserting into the post. The first snippet did nothing, so I removed it. Also, there is a Tidy button in the snippet editor. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do what you are looking for. But you can give a try to check below things.

Changed your html to below

```
<ul id="category1">
  <li><a href="#" class='subcategory'  id="subcategory1">Baby Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class='subcategory'  id="subcategory2">Drug Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class='subcategory'  id="subcategory3">Health and Personal Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class='subcategory'  id="subcategory4">Household Supplies</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="subItems"></div>
```

Changed your js code a bit to below

```
var selectedSubCategoryObj = null
$('#subcategory1').click(function() {
  $.getJSON("list.json",
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      let output = '';
      selectedSubCategoryObj= $(this)

      $.each(data[0].subcategories, function(index, product) {
        if($(selectedSubCategoryObj)[0].innerHTML == product.name){
          $.each(product.items, function(index, eachItem) {
          output += `
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="items">
                  <div class='photo'>
                      <img src="${eachItem.imagelink}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="info">
                      <h4>${eachItem.name}</h4>
                      <h5>$${eachItem.price}</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="info">
                      <p>
                          <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
       `;
        })
        $('#subItems').html(output);
      }
      });
    });
});
```

Once cross check if its similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: please I don't really understand what you explained, if you notice the html snippet above is just a category, how do I now cycle through the categories and it's subcategories

Comment: Since in your javascript, you used $.each(data[0].subcategories[0].items I felt its only for subcategories. and above code could work for it. Can you post how your JSON looks like so we can suggest looping out categories aswell.

Comment: just added the JSON

Comment: So in your example above, if you click on Baby care, what should happen?

Comment: it should display the items: soap, cream, dipers and dress

Comment: Updated answer. please check

Comment: Ok. first of all What are you expecting.. make it clear for us to check and make it work. And did you receive any error?